# Using a Higher Precision (than 8-bit unsigned integer) Buffered Image for Heightmaps in Java

Tags: java, heightmap

I am generating a heightmap for every quad in my quadtree in openCL. The way I was creating the image is as follows:

```
DataBufferInt dataBuffer =
            (DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
      int data[] = dataBuffer.getData();
      //img is a bufferedimage 
        inputImageMem = CL.clCreateImage2D(
        context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
        new cl_image_format[]{imageFormat}, size, size,
        size * Sizeof.cl_uint, Pointer.to(data), null);
```

This works ok but the major issue is that as the quads get smaller and smaller the 8-bit format of the buffered image starts to cause intolerable "stepping" issues as seen below:

[image]

I was wondering if there was an alternate way I could go about doing this?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Is this the "stepping" you're talking about? http://i.imgur.com/Sx9egmm.png?1

Comment: Yes, that it is.

Comment: Can you change the title to something more related to your question? I was trying to come up with something but didn't want to misinterpret your question.

Comment: Oh yea definitely

Comment: Why do you have to use a BufferedImage? What format are your input images?

Comment: I don't know what else I would use. The bufferedimage that is written to in the openCL kernel is of the type INT_RGB. Is there anyway to set up a buffered image using a floating point format?

Comment: The BufferedImage is not written to OpenCL. OpenCL doesn't interact with BufferedImages, but raw data instead. What you are doing in the code is getting the raw data from the BufferedImage and passing that to OpenCL. So the question is, why do you have BufferedImage in the process? What format is your height data originally before compressing it to 8-bits for BufferedImage?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using texture filtering when reading the height map? I'd expect that a bilinear filter would smooth things out a bit.

If you still need better precision then change the image format to something like CL_UNORM_INT16 or CL_FLOAT - see http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_image_format.html

I'm not quite sure how you do that from Java though.

Comment: Yea that's the issue: I can't figure out how to use anything other than 8-bit integer with a BufferedImage.

Comment: Since Java doesn't have native OpenCL support, it might help to know which library you're using. The other option would be to use a double width image, and decode it on the GPU as say (pixel[x]/256.0 + pixel[x+1]).

Comment: I tried using bilinear interpolation with no luck... I am just using Java OpenCL (JOCL)

Comment: The Java version of OpenCL seems to support these formats as well. `cl_image_format` has a `image_channel_data_type` member that can be used to specify the data format (eg. `CL_FLOAT` etc.)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html says BufferedImage supports TYPE_USHORT_GREY which is 16-bit.